# Get column values in flex datagrid

Tags: apache-flex

I want to get all values in one of the columns of a datagrid and put them in an array, to use it as a dataprovider of a combobox, is this possible?

I use an ArrayCollection as the dataprovider of the datagrid, it's filled from the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually,

```
var result:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection()
for each(var o:Object in myArrayCollection) {
    result.addItem(o.myField)
}
```

listen for `CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE` on you provider to know when it has been updated.